# In a 3x3 ANOVA (2 IV - each with 3 levels) interaction explained

Tags: anova

In a 3x3 ANOVA (2 IV - each with 3 levels)
is the interaction comparing 9 means or is it comparing the 2 main effects means?

Answer (score 0):

It can be useful to understand that the interaction from a 2-way ANOVA is equivalent to a comparison between two regression models. Here's an example (one factor has 3 levels, the other has 2 levels):

```
# Load in data
> install.packages("palmerpenguins")
> library(palmerpenguins)

# Run a standard 2-way anova - there's a significant interaction

> summary(aov(body_mass_g ~species*sex,data=penguins))
             Df    Sum Sq  Mean Sq F value   Pr(>F)    
species       2 145190219 72595110 758.358  < 2e-16 ***
sex           1  37090262 37090262 387.460  < 2e-16 ***
species:sex   2   1676557   838278   8.757 0.000197 ***
Residuals   327  31302628    95727                     
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
11 observations deleted due to missingness
```

This interaction result is the same one I would get if I compared a *regression* with no interaction (`model1`) to a regression with an interaction (`model2`).

```
> model1 = lm(body_mass_g ~species+sex,data=penguins)
> model2 = lm(body_mass_g ~species+sex+species:sex,data=penguins)
> anova(model1,model2)
Analysis of Variance Table

Model 1: body_mass_g ~ species + sex
Model 2: body_mass_g ~ species + sex + species:sex
  Res.Df      RSS Df Sum of Sq     F    Pr(>F)    
1    329 32979185                                 
2    327 31302628  2   1676557 8.757 0.0001973 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Looking deeper at `model2`, we see that there are *2* interactions added here:

```
> summary(model2)

Call:
lm(formula = body_mass_g ~ species + sex + species:sex, data = penguins)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-827.21 -213.97   11.03  206.51  861.03 

Coefficients:
                         Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)               3368.84      36.21  93.030  < 2e-16 ***
speciesChinstrap           158.37      64.24   2.465  0.01420 *  
speciesGentoo             1310.91      54.42  24.088  < 2e-16 ***
sexmale                    674.66      51.21  13.174  < 2e-16 ***
speciesChinstrap:sexmale  -262.89      90.85  -2.894  0.00406 ** 
speciesGentoo:sexmale      130.44      76.44   1.706  0.08886 .  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 309.4 on 327 degrees of freedom
  (11 observations deleted due to missingness)
Multiple R-squared:  0.8546,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.8524 
F-statistic: 384.3 on 5 and 327 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

So our anova interaction result is how much better the model fits when *all* the interactions are added to the linear regression.

Comment: I disagree. There is but one interaction, the interaction between species and sex, but it is represented with two terms. It is not required, however, that each interaction between categorical effects *must* be represented with all possible multiplicative effects, even though this is the "default" on virtually all statistical software.

Comment: Sure, *theoretically* we could construct an interaction another way. However, the question is about understanding the output from a 2-way ANOVA run in what is certainly the "default" method. My answer explains how the software arrives as this output.

Answer (score 0):

Your situation is described by a response variable $Y$ regressed on two categorical variables, $X, W$ each having 3 levels. In a $3 \times 3$ model without interaction, the linear model is as follows:
$$ E_1[Y|X,W] = \beta_0 + \beta_1 I(W=2) + \beta_2 I(W=3) + \beta_3 I(X=2) + \beta_4 I(X=3)$$

This is a 5 parameter model and it is not saturated. There are 9 distinct possible mean responses predicted by a combination of 5 covariates. A linear model without interaction is expressed as follows:

\begin{array}{ccc}
X & W & E_1[Y] \\ \hline
1 & 1 & \beta_0 \\ 
1 & 2 & \beta_0 + \beta_3\\
1 & 3 & \beta_0 + \beta_4\\
2 & 1 & \beta_0 +\beta_1\\
2 & 2 & \beta_0 +\beta_1+ \beta_3\\
2 & 3 & \beta_0 +\beta_1+ \beta_4\\
3 & 1 & \beta_0 +\beta_2\\
3 & 2 & \beta_0 +\beta_2+ \beta_3\\
3 & 3 & \beta_0 +\beta_2+ \beta_4\\
\end{array}

Because the number of parameters is smaller than the number of distinct means we know that the model is *not* saturated, and thus some constraint is imposed on this model. If you tell your software to "add an interaction" you have a new model:

$$ \begin{array}{rl}E_2[Y|X,W] &= \beta_0 + \beta_1 I(W=2) + \beta_2 I(W=3) + \beta_3 I(X=2) + \beta_4 I(X=3) + \\
& \gamma_1 I(W=2, X=2)) +
\gamma_2 I(W=2, X=3) + \\
& \gamma_3 I(W=3, X=2) + 
\gamma_4 I(W=3, X=3)\\
\end{array}
$$

This nine parameter model is saturated and each predicted $\hat{Y}$ corresponds to the group mean $Y$. That is:
\begin{array}{ccc}
X & W & E_2[Y] \\ \hline
1 & 1 & \beta_0 \\ 
1 & 2 & \beta_0 + \beta_3\\
1 & 3 & \beta_0 + \beta_4\\
2 & 1 & \beta_0 +\beta_1\\
2 & 2 & \beta_0 +\beta_1+ \beta_3 +\gamma_1\\
2 & 3 & \beta_0 +\beta_1+ \beta_4+\gamma_2\\
3 & 1 & \beta_0 +\beta_2\\
3 & 2 & \beta_0 +\beta_2+ \beta_3 + \gamma_3\\
3 & 3 & \beta_0 +\beta_2+ \beta_4 + \gamma_4\\
\end{array}

When you get the regression output you typically see hypothesis tests for *each* interaction term compared to the 0.05 level - as a default. Each $\gamma_i$ term is comparing 4 means. For instance, $\gamma_1$ is statistically significant if the 2-1 difference for the X and the W is not additive, that is the null hypothesis that $\gamma_1 = 0$ can be restated as $\mu_{X=2, W=2} - \mu_{X=1, W=1} \ne \beta_1 + \beta_2$ or equivalently $\mu_{X=2, W=2} - \mu_{X=2, W=1}  - \mu_{X=1, W=2} +  - \mu_{X=1, W=1} \ne 0$. In other words, each $\gamma_i$ compares **4** means.

However, the global test of significance for model 1 vs model 2 is a **4 degree of freedom test** that compares **all 9 mean levels**.